# deployment first ruby on rails app on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

For an university exam, I'm creating a Ruby on Rails app.

Currently, my app is working on http://localhost:3000/say/hello.

I would like to upload my app on Heroku web server. The problem is that it doesn't run the hello world program. Instead I see the start view of Ruby on Rails app: http://tecweb2.heroku.com/.

How do I get my hello world program to run on Heroku?

Comment: You'd want to go to http://tecweb2.heroku.com/say/hello but that seems to throw an error at the moment.  `heroku logs` will show you the logs so you can see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the instructions on that page, mainly delete the `public/index.html` page.

Answer (score 1):

you should use this command to understand whats going on

```
heroku logs
```

whatever shows up in red is what you are having problems with

here is the workflow that I use

create the heroku app

```
heroku create --stack cedar
```

push to your git repo

```
git push origin master
```

push to heroku repo

```
git push heroku master
```

rake the databse in heroku

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Here is the heroku getting started guide for rails 3

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3